# How do i copy/move all files and subfolders from the current directory to a Google Cloud Storage bucket with gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm using gsutil and I need to copy a large number of files/subdirectories from a directory on a windows server to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

I have checked the documentation but somehow I can't seem to get the syntax right - I'm trying something along these lines:

> c:\test>gsutil -m cp -r *.* gs://mytestbucket

But I keep getting the message:

> CommandException: No URLs matched: *.*

What am I doing wrong here?

Regards

Morten Hjorth Nielsen

Answer (score 4):

Try `gsutil -m cp -r * gs://mytestbucket`

Or `gsutil -m cp -r *.* gs://mytestbucket`

Or if your local directory is called `test` go one dir up and type: `gsutil -m cp -r test gs://mytestbucket`

Not sure which syntax you need on Windows, but probably the first.